# Phishing attempt through Booking.com

Tags: scams, booking.com

Attempted phishing where the perpetrator had all the reservation information, name etc. and directed user to a fake website where CC information was collected. The request was sent through the official booking.com site and showed up in the messages section where property messages usually show up (and also by email). User had to cancel and replace two credit cards (it 'failed' the first one but that CC was apparently tetchy so it didn't set off too many alarm bells).

User inquired of Booking.com before going to the false site but received no answer within 24 hours. The scammers cleverly redirected to the real booking.com if you went to the domain it looked like it was owned by booking.com. Only upon whois examination of the domain did the scam become obvious, which not everyone knows how to do.

[image]

Presumably this had to be a crooked employee at either Booking.com or at the property.

Is there anything the parties involve in this situation could have done better or to avoid a similar situation? Is it going to be safe for the user to pay at the property with a new CC?

Epilogue: the hotel in question indeed exists and is fairly well known. I think I can see how it would happen. They have a huge number of employees for the size of the place, likely paid less than 100 USD per month each. Actual in-person payment is via a machine with PIN so relatively secure, but likely the communications through Booking.com etc are not, so that presents a possible attack vector. Something to keep in mind.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it will probably get a better answer at: [Recently Active Questions - Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: What type of property was it (e.g big chain hotel, independent hotel, home let…)? What was the reason invoked for requesting card details? Was it supposed to be just card details (like for a guarantee or something similar) or for an actual payment? How did you end up knowing this was not legitimate?

Comment: @jcaron Independent hotel in SEA. Claim that card failed a security check or something of that ilk. The claim was that the room charge would be made and then reversed. In fact two test charges through google.com for 1 EUR were made and reversed.  The domain was registered in Reykjavík rather than Amsterdam where booking.com is, but more importantly it was registered just days before the scam using namecheap.com.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany did you actually enter the details on that site or was it on a third party payment gateway? If they just made two 1€ authorisations and then cancelled them, there is no actual damage to you other than the risk than someone has your card details and could use them later, right? But what prompted you to check the domain afterwards?

Comment: @MarkJohnson I doubt better answers can be had there, especially if any EU regulations apply (neither end was in the EU but booking.com is) and particularly for the second part of the question (is it safe), which is clearly a travel-related issue - most hotels require either a cash security deposit or a hold on the card.

Comment: @jcaron suspicion Damage is not really significant or important here (since it was caught early) though I guess the two banks are out the cost of couriers and remaking cards.

Comment: It is still a legal question since you are asking 'What responsibilities do the various parties have in this situation?'.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Maybe I'll reword it then. Nobody is going to be taking legal action for something like this.

Comment: I’m just not yet convinced there is anything actually wrong going on here, but I may have missed something. Have you been in contact with the hotel or with booking.com about this?

Comment: @jcaron No response from booking.com after talking with them in chat and sending screenshots, but looks like they've been in contact with the hotel since they sent a followup by the same means as the phishing: Here's what they had to say: 
 
 Everything is ok. and for the payment you can pay when you arrive at the hotel by cash or by card

Comment: Besides the payment going to a hotel, is this a travel question or is it a warning about a financial scam that might target other people booking hotel rooms?

Comment: On a different subject.  What did you blur out the domain name in the image?  Even if we don't know what the domain is, domain names are still public information.

Comment: @Willeke both, because any mistake should lead to changes to avoid such things happening in the future (or to others).

Comment: The domain appears to be parked now. I flagged it on Google. It was hotel-visitor dot com. I just didn't want anyone going there.

Comment: Have you been able to get in touch with the hotel via other means (specifically not contact information available through their booking.com listing)? Does the hotel actually exist?

Comment: @jcaron I still believe it exists, but that's a good question. I was thinking of asking them if the employee responsible still works there (making some presumptions, obviously, and see the reaction).

Comment: The first thing I would do is at least check if they actually have your booking. You probably don’t want arriving there to discover that the hotel is full and they know nothing about you because the whole listing was fake, or that the hotel just does not exist (or is closed or whatever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer here is to treat all communications from a property (directly or through booking companies) with some suspicion, as it is up to the individual property as to how securely they control access to basic information. Even if the communication has all your booking information and makes some legimate-looking reference to financial matters.

It does not necessarily reflect on how securely legitimate financial transactions are conducted.

Comment: My friend is scammed by this today. They are usually quite careful, but had lowered their guard since it came from an in-app message (I have to admit, I would probably have clicked the link too; although the website support window still looked off).